# Is function literal the same thing as Lambda expression and anonymous function?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Is **function literal** the same thing as **Lambda expression** and **anonymous function**?

Comment: No. I stumbled upon those expressions in multiple contexts referring to (I think) the same thing. I just want to make sure.

Comment: "function literal" is not a term that's really used in the Haskell world, but yes they are essentially the same things if you take their meanings from the JavaScript.

Comment: X literal means a simple expression with type X, excluding composite expressions (like `1+2`) and variables. A lambda expression/anonymous function fits exactly this definition.

Comment: Also, with constructs such as higher-order functions like `compose`, pattern matching, and partial application, there is less need for explicit lambda expressions.

Comment: @all Thank you very much :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is adequately answered in the comments:

"function literal" is not a term that's really used in the Haskell world, but yes they are essentially the same things if you take their meanings from the JavaScript. – Will Sewell 3 hours ago

`X` literal means a simple expression with type `X`, excluding composite expressions (like `1+2`) and variables. A lambda expression/anonymous function fits exactly this definition. – Bakuriu 3 hours ago